# Custom Authentication Middleware In MVC 6

Tags: middleware, asp.net-core-mvc

I am attempting to construct a piece of custom authentication middleware for MVC 6 and have some questions.

Firstly, is there anything available that demonstrates the *proper* way to implement custom authentication middleware?  I have tried to *hack* apart existing framework code but I have a feeling this is not the best approach.

After performing the aforementioned *hacking*, I ended up with something that looks like it may work but I am not sure why.

In my `Startup` class, I have added the following:

```
services.ConfigureAuthorization(auth =>
{
  auth.AddPolicy("TEST", new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().AddAuthenticationSchemes("TEST").RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build());
});
```

From here, if I add `[Authorize(Policy = "TEST")]` to a controller action, I can see things *working*, specifically, I can see that the `HandleUnauthorizedAsync` method of the authentication handler class is fired.  If I remove the `Policy` value from the `Authorize` attribute, I get an exception stating that "The following authentication scheme was not accepted:".

I have looked at the code that is created from the standard template and I do not see anything where an authorization policy is added.  Further, I can add the `Authorize` attribute without setting a value for `Policy` and it works (redirection to the login page occurs).

Why do I need the authorization policy in one instance but not the other?

One one hand, it works so I shouldn't worry but I like to understand how things work so I can better troubleshoot once real problems happen.

*** UPDATE ***

After some additional digging, I came across the `AutomaticAuthentication` property of the `AuthenticationOptions` object.  If I set this property to `true`, specifying a value for the `Policy` property of the `Authorize` attribute is no longer necessary.  This seems like a step in the right direction but I am still looking for some detail surrounding this finding if there is any to be had.

Comment: How did this turn out?